# finds key but not KEY.lower() in dictionary Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, uppercase, lowercase

So I need to write this program where I create a class and an object of that class is a dictionary with categories as keys, and words that are included in such categories are the values (Example: {'name' : {'patrick', 'jane'}, 'discipline' : {'geography',...}, ...}).

At some point in the program (in that class) I have to create a method which takes a the name of a category as an argument. I then have to pick a random word out of that category. In the dictionary all keys(categories) need to be lowercase but when I give a category to choose a word from that shouldn't matter.

Here is my code first (part of it):

```
import random
class MadLibs:
    def __init__(self, woordenschat = {}):
        self.woordenschat = woordenschat

    def suggereren(self, categorie):
        assert categorie.lower() in self.woordenschat, 'onbekende categorie'
        randwoord = random.choice(list(self.woordenschat[categorie.lower()]))

        if categorie.isupper():
            return randwoord.upper()
        elif categorie.islower():
            return randwoord
        else:
            return randwoord.capitalize()
```

so say I got a category 'name' as key in my dictionary with a sequence of words, when  I then use the method *suggereren* and give as argument 'name' it works, but when I give 'NAME' then self.woordenschat[category.lower()] returns an empty list (see the line where I initialize **randwoord** )

Would somebody be able to tell me why this happens?

UPDATE:

this is how you add the words in the dictionary, categorie is where you give the category, and woorden is where you give new words that belong to that category

```
def leren(self, categorie, woorden):
        if isinstance(woorden, (tuple, list, set)):
            woorden = set(woorden)
        else:
            woorden = {woorden}

        if categorie in self.woordenschat:
            self.woordenschat[categorie.lower()].add(woord.lower() for woord in woorden)
        else:
            self.woordenschat[categorie.lower()] = (woord.lower() for woord in woorden)
        return None
```

UPDATE:

seems like the way I added the words in leren was the problem an error something like: object 'generator' does not have ... 'add'

here's my new code:

```
def leren(self, categorie, woorden):
        if isinstance(woorden, (tuple, list, set)):
            woorden = set(woorden)
        else:
            woorden = {woorden}
        set_to_add = {woord.lower() for woord in woorden}
        if categorie in self.woordenschat:
            self.woordenschat[categorie.lower()].union(set_to_add)
        else:
            self.woordenschat[categorie.lower()] = (set_to_add)
        return None
```

now the only problem left is that my object doesn't really get updated when I add new words to an existing category I'll try to find it first but if I don't I'll just ask a new question.

update: nevermind found it, twas a stupid mistake

Comment: Does the assert fail in that case?

Comment: yes it does, which only adds to my confusion

Comment: I've tested the code and it works fine... Dus geen idee :(

Comment: Please show the line where you initalize your MadLibs instance

Comment: `def __init__(self, woordenschat = {}):` Never use a mutable default value.
Instead, `def __init__(self, woordenschat = None): ; if woordenschat  is None: ;  self.woordenschat  = {}`

Comment: Okay, I'll get right to that , but could it be that when there's only one word in the category it doesn't work or when I first use 'name' it then removes the word from the object because that's how it needs to be tested

Comment: @DeepSpace tried that but doesn't get rid of the problem, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: @zjordi: Where do you fill your woordenschat with values? Could there be for any reason be an incompatible type for the keys?

Comment: In leren(self, categorie, woorden), if it's a new category I create a new key and add the given words as values, if it already exists I update it, I don't see any reason why it would be incompatible myself

Answer (score 0):

actually , in the requests sources code , there have a solution about the caselessdict object maybe satisfied you need.

```
import collections

class CaseInsensitiveDict(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, data=None, **kwargs):
        self._store = dict()
        if data is None:
            data = {}
        self.update(data, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # Use the lowercased key for lookups, but store the actual
        # key alongside the value.
        self._store[key.lower()] = (key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._store[key.lower()][1]

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._store[key.lower()]

    def __iter__(self):
        return (casedkey for casedkey, mappedvalue in     self._store.values())

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._store)

    def lower_items(self):
        """Like iteritems(), but with all lowercase keys."""
        return (
        (lowerkey, keyval[1])
        for (lowerkey, keyval)
        in self._store.items()
    )

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, collections.Mapping):
            other = CaseInsensitiveDict(other)
        else:
            return NotImplemented
        # Compare insensitively
        return dict(self.lower_items()) == dict(other.lower_items())

    # Copy is required
    def copy(self):
        return CaseInsensitiveDict(self._store.values())

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(dict(self.items()))

    @property
    def keys(self):
        return [i for i in self]
    @property
    def values(self):
        return [self[i] for i in self]
```

Comment: While I don't understand all of this (I've only just started working with classes) I don't think this would work in my case as I have to do this for school and I have restrictions to what my class object is because it is tested with PYTHIA

Comment: you see self._store = dict() , it store the lower key , and have the value (key,value) : the key is the original name , and the value is the value , when you use dict['what'] like that , actually it use the inner method `__getitem__` so , it where find the lower case and get the value ([1]) , so  the whole mechanism will query as a lower case and caseless .

Comment: I found my problem, it was the way I added the words that seemed to mess up finding the values, although now there's a new problem but I'll try to figure it out myself first, thanks anyway